# How to call a function that is inside another function javascript

Tags: javascript, function, function-calls

I have two files as below:

> ```
> trycapture.js (which has) trycapture() (which has) drawaggregate() definition
> main.js from which I want to call drawaggregate();
> ```

**trycapture.js**

```
trycapture(){
... some code
function drawaggregate(){
... definition
   }
}
```

**main.js**

```
.. some variables
var try_obj = new trycapture();
try_obj.drawAggregate(emit_x1,emit_y1,emit_x2,emit_y2);
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
<script src="trycapture.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

How can I call that function. I tried creating an object right before calling drawaggregation() such as above:

I still get the error:

> TypeError:try_obj.drawaggregate is not a function

Also, in index.html I made sure that I include trycapture.js before main.js How can I call that function?

Comment: Can you post the complete code?

Comment: Can you include some actual code for how your functions are set up?

Comment: without seeing your source code there's no way to help solve your problem. Please review [ask], and include a [mcve]. Otherwise, this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic) and should be closed as such.

Comment: `console.log(try_obj)` first to see what's actually in `try_obj`. Is it creating the object you expect? Is your call to `drawaggregate` using the correct capitalization, spelling, etc? Some more code would probably be useful here :)

Comment: Are you including both files in your HTML page? Is trycapture.js included before main.js?

Comment: There's a lot of things being thrown at you in these comments, but basically we just need to know how you're loading your JavaScript files. HTML source would help.

Comment: @zzzzBov added sample code

Comment: @gcampbell added html head code

Comment: @sander console.log(try_obj) shows 'trycapture{}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
this.drawaggregate = drawaggregate;
```

after your function definition to make it a public method of the trycapture object.

---

Overall, you will change your trycapture.js to the following:

```
function trycapture(){
    ... some code

    // Locally accessible only
    function drawaggregate(){
        ... definition
    }
    this.drawaggregate = drawaggregate; // Makes it publicly accessible also
}
```

---

the `drawaggregate()` method can then be called like so:

```
var try_obj = new trycapture();
try_obj.drawaggregate();
```

Comment: I am able to call the function even without the object now. Is that normal?

Comment: Yes, it's normal. It depends on many things and more than can fit in this comment box. So explaining here could be incomplete and confusing. EXAMPLE1: If you happen to call your `new trycapture()` from inside an anonymous function such as an `onload` event listener, then `this` inside of `trycapture` would refer to the `window` object instead. Thus, `drawaggregate` would become a global window function callable from anywhere. EXAMPLE2: If you are inside the `trycapture` function namespace, you are allowed to(and should) call `drawaggregate` as a local function instead of a method of an object.